# Javascript display inner html for a div with id

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to display all inner html content inside a div with plain javascript?

[MyFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcqVC/305/)

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    some-value
  </div>
</div>
<div id="output">

</div>
```

I am trying to use outerhtml

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = parent.outerHtml;
```

Comment: i tried parent.innerHTML but no luck.

Comment: you must use innerText with outerHTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled `outerHTML` (HTML in all capital). But to show HTML tags as well, use `innerText` instead

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
document.getElementById("output").innerText = parent.outerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    some-value
  </div>
</div>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: I am trying to pull html tags also.

Comment: Ah, ok... then just swap `innerHTML` with `innerText`

Comment: Also: to keep whitespace, either use `<pre>` or the CSS property [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Comment: Can we do a console.log the html content instead of appending to output element?

Comment: Sure. Just remove the second line and use console.log instead

Answer (score 2):

Use `innerText` with `outerHTML`

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
document.getElementById("output").innerText = parent.outerHTML;
```

```css
#output {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    some-value
  </div>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Can we do a console.log the html content instead of appending to output element?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create everything from Javascript only. Look at this example.

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
var nodeDiv = document.createTextNode("Pay attention! This is new.");
div.appendChild(nodeDiv);
var element = document.getElementById("parent");
element.appendChild(div);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    some-value
  </div>
</div>
```